# Ошибки типов в Haskell

Tags: haskell

Начал изучать Haskell, попробовал реализовать на нём простейший метод бисекции, но что-то не так с типами. Вот код:

```
mpd a b e = 
let
  c = (a+b) / 2
  func x = 10*x + x^2 + (2*x)^((-x+2)^3) - 8
in
  if abs (b-a) > e then 
    if func a * func c < 0 then 
      mpd a c e 
    else 
      mpd c b e
  else
    c

main = putStrLn $ "x = " ++ show (mpd (-100000) 100000 0.000001)
```

На выражении "x - 5" работало, а на этом перестало компилироваться. Падает с ошибками:

> main.hs:14:29:
>     No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `show'
>     The type variable`a0' is ambiguous
>     Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
>     Note: there are several potential instances:
>       instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
>       instance Show Float -- Defined in`GHC.Float'
>       instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
>         -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
>       ...plus 23 others
>     In the second argument of`(++)', namely
>       `show (mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'
>     In the second argument of`($)', namely
>       `"x = " ++ show (mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'
>     In the expression:
>       putStrLn $ "x = " ++ show (mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)
>
> main.hs:14:35:
>     No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of `mpd'
>     The type variable`a0' is ambiguous
>     Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
>     Note: there are several potential instances:
>       instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
>       instance Integral Integer -- Defined in`GHC.Real'
>       instance Integral GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
>     In the first argument of`show', namely
>       `(mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'
>     In the second argument of`(++)', namely
>       `show (mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'
>     In the second argument of`($)', namely
>       `"x = " ++ show (mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'
>
> main.hs:14:40:
>     No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of syntactic negation
>     The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
>     Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
>     Note: there are several potential instances:
>       instance Num Double -- Defined in`GHC.Float'
>       instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
>       instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
>         -- Defined in`GHC.Real'
>       ...plus three others
>     In the first argument of `mpd', namely`(- 100000)'
>     In the first argument of `show', namely`(mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'
>     In the second argument of `(++)', namely`show (mpd (- 100000) 100000 0.000001)'

Comment: Добавьте тип к функции `mpd`. Видимо, такой:

    mdp :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double

Comment: Пробовал.. Пишет следующее:

    main.hs:8:10:
    No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `func'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Double)
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `func a'
    In the first argument of `(<)', namely `func a * func c'
    In the expression: func a * func c < 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл. Проблема в выражении и заключалась: использовал для степени (^), а надо было (**), так как первый подходит только если второй операнд - целочисленный.